# C# database Combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, local-database

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it - Well,I'd like to have an option to choose between two things in one combobox - "Sells" and "Services".Under this combobox there will be another combobox , which will be waiting to see what will the user choose between "Sells" and "Services" , if "Sells" is choosen then in the second combobox the user to have options between "authoparts","autoequipment","cars" if "Services" - "full service","replacement of consumables","purchase of vehicles".Thank you very much for the given time

Comment: This is often called "cascading drop downs", and I'm sure there are many examples online.  The idea is that you listen for the event of changing the value in the first form element, and in response to that you build/modify/show/etc. the second element.

Comment: Sounds pretty straightforward, can you post the code you have done so far so we can help you figure out what's wrong?

Comment: What platform do you use? Winforms, Asp.Net, MVC, WPF???